# Binding List To GridView And Update GridView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In my page I am binding a GridView using List.I have different fields on my page and storing those fields values into list and binding it with a Grid.

It is working well but now i want to update Gridview using checkbox in gridview,on clicking on checkbox the associated values in that row comes on the different fields and on button save click gridview should be updated.

Not sure how to go about it.

My Code Sample is Like This:

**aspx**

```
<table class="tblPopUp">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCaste" CssClass="Label" runat="server" Text="Caste"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCaste" runat="server" CssClass="Dropdownlist myddlinPopUp"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblNo_OfPosition" CssClass="Label" runat="server" Text="No Of Position"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoOfPositioninPopUp" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox mytextboxinPopUp"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMinAge" CssClass="Label" runat="server" Text="Min Age"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinAge" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox mytextboxinPopUp"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMaxAge" CssClass="Label" runat="server" Text="Max Age"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaxAge" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox mytextboxinPopUp"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                    
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInPopUpReservation" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveInPopUpReservation_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:GridView ID="gridReservationDetails" runat="server" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridview" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Caste" DataField="casteName" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="No Of Position" DataField="NoOfPosition" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Min Age" DataField="MinAge" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Max Age" DataField="MaxAge" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
public class CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails
{
    public int casteID { get; set; }
    public string casteName { get; set; }
    public int NoOfPosition { get; set; }
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
}

protected List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails> FillReservation()
{
    List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails> lst = new List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails>();
    List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails> lstPrevious = new List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails>();
    lstPrevious = (List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails>)Session["cprrd"];
    if (lstPrevious != null)
    {
        CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails obj = new CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails();
        obj.casteID = int.Parse(ddlCaste.SelectedValue);
        obj.casteName = ddlCaste.SelectedItem.ToString();
        obj.NoOfPosition = int.Parse(txtNoOfPositioninPopUp.Text);
        obj.MaxAge = int.Parse(txtMaxAge.Text);
        obj.MinAge = int.Parse(txtMinAge.Text);
        lstPrevious.Add(obj);
        Session["cprrd"] = lstPrevious;
        return lstPrevious;
    }
    else
    {
        CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails obj = new CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails();
        obj.casteID = int.Parse(ddlCaste.SelectedValue);
        obj.casteName = ddlCaste.SelectedItem.ToString();
        obj.NoOfPosition = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfPositioninPopUp.Text);
        obj.MaxAge = Convert.ToInt32(txtMaxAge.Text);
        obj.MinAge = Convert.ToInt32(txtMinAge.Text);
        lst.Add(obj);
        Session["cprrd"] = lst;
        return lst;
    }
}


protected void btnSaveInPopUpReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CommonHRMS_PositionRequisitionReservationDetails> lst = FillReservation();
    gridReservationDetails.DataSource = lst;
    gridReservationDetails.DataBind();        
}
```

Comment: You question is too vauge. "On clicking on checkbox the associated values in that row comes on the different fields and on button save click gridview should be updated." 

What do you mean by difrent fields? That's a poperty or control or pop up? Do Specify .

Comment: that are the controls "textbox and dropdownlist" in form

Comment: i am getting values from textboxes and dropdownlist to fill list,and after that i m binding list to grid

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGridViewID.Rows)

{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxName");

    if (check.Checked)
    {
        //Button Event Here
    }
    else
    {
        //Else Part..!
    }
}
```